# Can't receive jpeg image from server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sockets

I am trying to receive a jpeg image from my c# server. The weird thing is when I run it with the debugger and have a break point anywhere in the method it works perfectly fine. Without a breakpoint then I get this error

Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment

Here is my code

```
(void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
NSMutableData *data;
data = [NSMutableData new];
switch(eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        uint8_t buffer[1024];
        int len;

        while([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];

            if (len > 0)
            {
                [data appendBytes:(const void*)buffer length:sizeof(buffer)];
            }
        }
        UIImage *images = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
        [dvdCover setImage:images];
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
    {
        //UIImage *images = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
        //[dvdCover setImage:images];


    } break;
}
```

}

Comment: errr. you're creating the image before the end of the stream. of course it will be corrupt. Running with the debugger probably introduces a latency which will cause the has bytes call to give a completed set of data.  You need to uncomment out the bit in stream end, and comment it out in the available bit.

Comment: The problem I run into with that is the nsstreameventencountered never gets called.

Comment: I think it's better if you can find out how long the image is going to be beforehand -- so you know when to stop appending bytes. When that happen then you can construct your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hi you can check this code hop it will help you...

case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
{

uint32_t max_size = 1000000;  // Max size of the received imaged you can modify it as your reqirement.
        NSMutableData* buffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: max_size];
        NSInteger totalBytesRead = 0;
        NSInteger bytesRead = [(NSInputStream *)stream read: [buffer mutableBytes] maxLength: max_size];
        if (bytesRead != 0) {
            while (bytesRead > 0 && totalBytesRead + bytesRead < max_size) {
                totalBytesRead+= bytesRead;
                bytesRead = [(NSInputStream *)stream read: [buffer mutableBytes] + totalBytesRead maxLength: max_size - totalBytesRead];
            }
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            else {
                // read failure, report error and bail (not forgetting to release buffer)
            }
            [buffer setLength: totalBytesRead];
            yourImageName.image = [UIImage imageWithData: buffer];
            [buffer release];

}  break;
```

Comment: This gets me my image but it ends up taking about a minute before it appears. Why is it taking so long?

Comment: @user1585542 image come in data bytes so it's take time to load or if your image size is more for example 5 MB or more than load time will increase.

Comment: Thanks for your help skyline. The image is only 37KB so I find it strange that it would take over a minute to send. It would send instantly with my first solution and one debug stop. Any ideas how I could try and speed it up?

Comment: @user1585542 this link will help you to understand process of send/receive data over socket programming:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388514/sending-a-huge-amount-of-real-time-processed-data-via-udp-to-iphone-from-a-serve

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are assuming the whole JPEG image will be transferred in one chunk, and you can just read it with one occurence of 'HasBytesAvailable' event. However you should also consider the case where the JPEG image is transferred to you in multiple chunks.

It might work for you if you set breakpoint, because your code execution might be halted somewhere, and your network buffer had plenty time to receive all bytes of the image. But without breakpoints it might not have time to do so.

Try refactoring your code to accumulate the bytes chunk, and only assume it's done when all bytes have been transferred. (Normally you have to know beforehand how many bytes the image is going to be -- or you can just capture the end of stream event)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to sockets and network programming. How would I go about doing that?